# How can I pre-populate the value of a text box from another html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have 2 HTML files in a same directory.

I have a HTML1.html file.

In my HTML2.html, I want to place a textbox and when the page loads, I want to pre-populate the textbox with the complete HTML source code from "HTML1.html" file.

How can I do that?

Comment: You could use AJAX to retrieve the HTML of the other page.

Comment: Can you please show me an example so I understand how it is done in Ajax?

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials and examples if you research. Here's the jQuery docs which cover it: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/